# Is there a topological group that is connected but not path-connected?

Tags: abelian-groups, topological-groups, connectedness, uniform-spaces

Is there a $\big($[T$_0$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_space)$\hspace{-0.02 in}\big)$ [topological group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_space) that is connected but not path-connected?

If yes:

$\quad$ Can it be [complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_space#Completeness)? $\:$ (with respect to the two-sided [uniform structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_space#Examples))

$\quad$ Can it be abelian?

$\quad$ Can it be abelian and complete? $\:$ (simultaneously)

Searching online for various combinations of "topological group", "connected",

and "path-connected" did not turn up anything related to this question.

Comment: How about http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solenoid_%28mathematics%29

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes to all questions (as implicit in the comments, so I put cw). Indeed the solenoid defined as the inverse limit of the sequence of surjective endomorphisms $\mathbf{R}/\mathbf{Z}$ given by multiplication by 2 is a compact, metrizable, connected and not path-connected group.