# topological group that is connected and locally connected but not path-connected

Tags: topological-groups, connectedness

Is there a $\hspace{.01 in}\big($[T$_{\hspace{.01 in}0}$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_space)$\hspace{-0.02 in}\big)\hspace{.01 in}$ [topological group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_group) that is connected

*and* locally connected but is not path-connected?

([This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/501049) does not have the local connectedness condition.)

Comment: I think, the additive group of nonstandard real numbers will be a counter example.

Comment: That won't be connected, since it won't be Dedekind-complete. $\;$

Comment: Yes, I just realized this too.

Comment: This question was asked and answered at MathOverflow: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/149754/topological-group-that-is-connected-and-locally-connected-but-not-path-connected/